# Сброс цикла jQuery, выполнение заново

Tags: jquery, циклы, javascript

Имеется функция формирования чисел из картинок:

```
function setCounterToNumber(index, num, container)
{
    var nums = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
    $('.'+container+' #counter > div:eq('+index+')').stop();
    for(i=0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        $('.'+container+' #counter > div:eq('+index+')').children('.top').delay(100).animate({height:'0px'},100,function()
        {
            if(nums[index]+1 > 10) next_num = 1; else next_num = nums[index]+1;

            $(this).attr('src','/digits/'+nums[index]+'.png').css('height','19px').prev().attr('src','/digits/'+(next_num) +'.png');

            $('.'+container+' #counter > div:eq('+index+')').children('.bottom_high').animate({height:'19px'},100,function()
            {
                $(this).attr('src','/digits/'+(next_num)+'-d.png').css('height','0px').prev().attr('src','/digits/'+(nums[index]) +'-d.png');
                nums[index]++;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

+имеется обработчик `mouseenter`, если наводим курсор на определенный `div` (их несколько), то запускается формирование этих изображений. Проблема заключается в следующем: когда быстро водить курсором сразу по нескольким `div`'ам, то получается, что цифры будут формироваться ровно столько, сколько раз я провел курсором по этим `div`'aм.

Нужно, чтобы при наводке курсора на `div`, цикл сбрасывался и начинался заново. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А давайте глянем с другой стороны: раз нам не нужен просчет при наведении на каждый блок, то не лучше ли добавить таймер, который бы запускал скрипт просчета через n количество времени и который бы очищался при следующем наведении мыши на блок?

Т.е.:

```
var timer;

$('img').on('mouseenter', function() {
   clearTimeout(timer);

   timer = setTimeout(function() {

      setCounterToNumber();

   }, 100); // 100ms
});
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы формирование этих картинок останавливалось при наведении на друой div и начиналось заного. К сожалению, вариант что предложили вы - не совсем подходит. Хотел скинуть код обработчика, но символов в комментарии не хватает.

Comment: @roman_r тогда добавьте ключ в цикл, который будет его прерывать:



    var keyForWhile = false;
    
    
    $('img').on('mouseenter', function() {
     
     keyForWhile = true;
     setCounterToNumber();
    });
    
    function setCounterToNumber(index, num, container) {
     keyForWhile = false;
     
     if(keyForWhile) {
      break;
     }
     ...
    }